# How to solve this nullPointer Exception in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to jasper report, I need to create pdf document with BeanDatasource and subreport.
I refer the following blog " http://knol.google.com/k/jasper-reports-working-with-beans-and-sub-report# " . I followed all the steps perfectly. While i am running the report using IReport i can get the pdf document with the content. But when we try to create from java program i m getting exception in the following line

Line number 110: " **JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("C:/JasperReports/contacts.jasper", parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(TestPerson.getBeanCollection()));** "

and this is the following error i am getting in my Eclipse Console window .

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesMap.readObject(JRPropertiesMap.java:185)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:88)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(JRLoader.java:257)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:308)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:257)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:275)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:426)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:1380)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:692)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:113)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:891)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:814)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
>     at test.TestJasperReport.main(TestJasperReport.java:110)

Comment: Could you post the code leading up to the line JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("C:/JasperReports/contacts.jasper", parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(TestPerson.getBeanCollection())); "

Comment: I have reproduced this problem in a different context: `JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(myURL.openStream(), paramsMap, dataSource)` where all of the parameters are non-null and myURL.openStream() is an open .jasper file.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and found that iReports had had an auto update and that the files it produces were no longer compatible with the version of Jasper being brought into the build of my application.

I resolved this by ensuring that I had downloaded the very latest iReports and the very latest Jasper Reports.

iReport v3.7.4 and Jasper Reports v3.7.4.

Comment: upgrading to latest versions for all the jars (here itext, jasperreports, commons-loggins) used in my application helped me and solved my issue.

Comment: how do you get the relevant up-to-date jars for the version of iReport you're using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like on of the properties you are passing to your report is null.

I would suggest stepping through your code in debug.